# Multicasting of cold signals in RAC3/4

Tags: reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

I want to have two cold `SignalProducer`s B and C, both of them depends on other cold `SignalProducer` A, which emits db entity objects — so it's critical for me to multicast so exactly same object arrive to both B and C. Here is some graph:

```
     --(transformations)--B
    /
-A ----(transformations)--C
```

But because B and C has some transformations, which may require significant amount of work, I don't want them to happen until they are connected.

In RAC2 we had `[[RACSignal`[`-publish]`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/3fb9944591f0590a4c344d56bcb6db805871ac85/ReactiveCocoa/Objective-C/RACSignal%2BOperations.m#L950)[`-autoconnect`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/e16f47cf9cb568136ebd81430b24af274c3c27c7/ReactiveCocoa/Objective-C/RACMulticastConnection.m#L64)`]` which worked ok in this case.

As [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#using-startwithsignal-instead-of-multicasting) says, multicasting from RAC2 made cleaner with `startWithSignal`, but it 1) starts immediately, 2) pushes me to use hot signal all over the rest of the chain

[`SignalProducer.buffer`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#using-signalproducerbuffer-instead-of-replaying) seems so be an acceptable solution.

What is the proper solution in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I reimplemented `-publish` `-autoconnect` from RAC2 in RAC3/Swift1.2 like that:

```
func buffer<T, E>(capacity: Int) -> SignalProducer<T, E> -> SignalProducer<T, E> {
    return { (signal: SignalProducer<T, E>) -> SignalProducer<T, E> in

        let (buffer, bufferSink) = SignalProducer<T, E>.buffer(capacity)
        var connectionsCount = 0
        var upperDisposable: Disposable? = nil

        let addSubscriber: ()->() = {
            if (connectionsCount == 0) {
                upperDisposable = signal.start(bufferSink)
            }
            connectionsCount++
        }

        let removeSubscriber: ()->() = {
            connectionsCount--
            if connectionsCount == 0 {
                upperDisposable?.dispose()
                upperDisposable = nil
            }
        }


        return SignalProducer { (sink, disposable) in
            disposable.addDisposable(removeSubscriber)
            sendNext(sink, buffer)
            addSubscriber()
        }
        |> flatten(.Concat)
    }
}
```

It's not thread safe and probably can contain other issues